# IOS cross domain API

Tags: javascript, angular

On angular js :
I have two website.

Website 1.
Website 2.

When Website 1 user's connect, it use the website 2 to fetch the API and it set cookies on website 2. (session)
Sadly, on IOS Safari it does not work because Apple policy restrict cookie set.

Any idea how to make it works ?

I tried something like this :

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
                config.headers['Authorization']= 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
             //   config.headers['Dodo'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            console.log('HTTPrequest');
            }
           // config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==';
           // config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';

            return config;
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to REST API, You can save the Authorization token in your shared storage and pass them in the headers as in the example you have shown